# How to make WPF XBAP work in Cefsharp (chrome)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, xbap, cefsharp

I am working on WPF XBAP application. It works in IE. It is not working in firefox and chrome. I searched and put a bunch of dlls inside google/chrome/Application path. still it didn't work.

I put npwpf.dll in c:/programfiles(x86)/MozillaFirefox/plugins folder, still it didn't worked in firefox. When opening the firefox plugins page in browser, I can't able to see WPF plugin there. I tried reinstalling .net 3.5, still plugin didn't show up.

To briew, could someone help me to know how I can make WPF XBAP to work in cefsharp and chrome.

Thanks.

Comment: jQuery mobile and Knockout js do not get along well, because knockout.js relies too much on the DOM, just like jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting nspr4 dll in c:/programfiles(x86)/MozillaFirefox/plugins,

then restart browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting xpcom dll and change the Environment path to "c:/programfiles(x86)/MozillaFirefox/plugins"